# simple regex match

Tags: regex

What would be a regex that matches "nl" OR "fr" (without the quotes) but nothing else, case insensitive?

Comment: you mean `'nl'` **or** `'fr'`.

Comment: Can you elaborate with examples of what you do and don't want matching as full strings. Are you looking for independent strings of "nl" and "fr"; not "from" or "only", or are you looking for any match of "nl" and "fr" whilst ignoring what surrounds them. Also, where you say "and" do you mean && specifically or just any case of either appearing? For regex, this link might help: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Indeed, it is nl or fr. I'm using this for routing rules in codeigniter. Thanks SilentGhost

Comment: You know that you can edit your question and change that `and` to `or` - don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatives in regular expressions are expressed as expressions separated by the `|` character.

```
nl|fr
```

Case-insensitivity is specified in different ways, in different languages. One way that will work everywhere is to be explicit.

```
[nN][lL]|[fF][rR]
```

If you want "the whole string" to be one of those two phrases, then you must *anchor* it.

```
^([nN][lL]|[fF][rR])$
```

Comment: [nN][lL]|[fF][rR], dude that's sick! +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
^(nl|fr)$
```

And use the case `i`nsensitive flag.

And I assume you meant nl *or* fr, and not nlfr.

Answer (score 2):

with regex, (`i` for case-insensitive)

```
/^(nl|fr)$/i
```

without regex, in your favourite language, just use the equality operator

```
mystring == "nl" or mystring == "fr"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's:

```
(nl|fr)
```